# is password field clearing now automatic in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails

Having upgraded an app (in progress) to 3.1 I had to change a test for clearing the password and password confirmation fields.  Rather than testing for an empty value attribute I had to test for a missing value attribute.

That was fine, but when I went to turn off the field clearing to make the test fail, it still passed, because the fields were still cleared (the value was still missing).  Previously I had lines in the appropriate controller under create to clear the fields if user creation failed (so the fields would be empty when the form was redisplayed).  Now it appears that is no longer necessary.

Is this default behavior now for password and confirmation fields?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

From the [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/CHANGELOG):

> *Rails 3.0.0 (August 29, 2010)*
>
> - password_field renders with nil value by default making the use of passwords secure by default

And the [original commit here](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/1851af84c1c7244dc416be9c93a4700b70e801e3).